# I have installed Kotlin plugin in my Eclipse IDE and when I am running my Kotlin program using some predefined function it shows error

Tags: kotlin, runtime-error, classnotfoundexception

I have  installed Kotlin plugin in my Ecilipse IDE and when I am running my Kotlin program using some predefined function it shows this error

Error: Could not find or load main class FirstKotlinProgKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FirstKotlinProgKt

This is only happening when I am using predefined Kotlin Functions like uppercase()
It works find while only using Printing statements
I have Added Picture for better understanding.
ThankYou

[image]

Comment: Do you have linting on? Maybe an import is missing, or the Kotlin default library cannot be found. How is your project built - is it a maven or gradle project?

Comment: Is there anything shown in the `Problems` view? Can you show the contents of the `Error Log` view (`Window`>`Show View`)?

Comment: @TreffnonX it's neither a Maven nor Gradle project.